# Pistachio Problem

Tags: probability

I have a bag of 100 pistachio nuts. I pick one our blindly and see if it edible. If it edible I eat it and throw the shells back in the bad. I pick up one more blindly and see it is edible. If it is edible I repeat the above. If it is not edible I throw it back in the bag. The probability of a picking up edible pistachio vs non edible pistachio is 1/20. How many tries would it take to eat all edible pistachios ?

Comment: Just to be sure: the number of "shells" in the bag always accounts to 100, correct?

Comment: Your probability assumption just means that there are exact $5$ inedible nuts in the bag, yes?  Of course the number of edible ones goes down over time (or at least, it is expected to).  After a few (edible ones) have been eaten, are you assuming that the person might draw an empty shell later on?  Usually it's pretty clear which shells contain nuts and which do not...

Comment: @lulu Problem's language suggests (perhaps wrongly) that the OP (i.e. original poster) has more or less reproduced the original problem.  I see contradictory indications re re-attempting to eat a (once eaten) pistachio.  On the one hand, the natural assumption is that you can't eat or try to eat an empty shell.  Alternatively, why the specification that "If it edible I eat it and throw the shells back in the bag" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that the numbers of shells (edible,empty and not) remains 100 throughout the whole process then this is exactly the [Coupon's collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), thus since the in the initial bag there are (about) 5 edible pistachios, the expected number of tries is
$$\frac{1}{\frac{5}{100}}+\frac{1}{\frac{4}{100}}+\frac{1}{\frac{3}{100}}+\frac{1}{\frac{2}{100}}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{100}}\cong20+25+33+50+100=228$$

If instead you throw away the shells, it's easy to adapt the formula...

Comment: Unclear to me which interpretation was intended by the problem composer.  See my comment following the originally posted question.  Perhaps it would be worthwhile for you to expand your answer to also provide the alternate computation.

Comment: I explicitly wanted to leave something for the OP to do in that case.